# What's wrong with defining a reference to a pointer to a const data with non-const pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
int main()
{
    const int* x;
    int* pa = x;//removes const, so UB.

    const int*& pb = pa;//error
    int* pd = pb;//error
    return 0;
}
```

I know that it's not possible to define a `pointer to non-const data` with a `pointer to const data`, because it would automatically cancel the constness out allowing me to modify the value.
But what is wrong with the second initialization? I know that a reference is an alias of something and how it works, but still don't get what actually is happening there at all. I guess that explanation of the second error will, hopefully, enlighten me the third error.
Can anyone shed some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const int x = 1;
int* p;
const int*& r = p;
```

Imagine we had gotten this far. This last line will give the error you're questioning, but let's assume it works. Now `r` and `p` refer to the same pointer object. But now we can do this:

```
r = &x;
```

This makes `r` point at the `const` object `x`, which you might think is fine, but it will also make `p` point at it. Since `p` is an `int*` (not `const`), we can now use `p` to modify `x`:

```
*p = 2;
```

Now we've changed the value of a `const` object. The error in question prevents us from doing this.

So basically, the reasoning for this error is that being able to bind a reference to pointer to `const` to a pointer to non-`const` would give you a way to get the non-`const` pointer to point at a `const` object. That's bad.

See the [Why am I getting an error converting a `Foo**` → `Foo const**`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html) C++ FAQ to learn about the same issue but with pointers instead of references. The reasoning is the same.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I'd summarize it like: A reference must be exactly the same type as the referenced object, otherwise there would be an object defined in an ambiguous way.

Comment: @DanielKatz It can add `const` to the "top level" type. So you can initialise a `int* const&` with an `int*`.

Comment: I always confuse myself when trying to explain this to others, but your explanation is very clear.

Comment: This is the square-rectangle OO problem. A classic bad OO design is that "`Square`s are a subclass of `Rectangl`e". But this isn't true, because `Rect.SetWidth(7); Rect.SetHeight(9); Assert(63 == Rect.GetArea());` is true for every `Rectangle`, but not true for a `Square`.  `ReadOnlySquare`s are a subclass of `ReadOnlyRectangle`s.  The same thing happens here -- read only access to a `int const**` is identical to read only access to a `int**`, but `int const**` is-not-a `int**` because writing to a restricted subtype is not the same as reading from one. C#'s in/out types would be useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure I really agree with this explanation. `int*` and `const int*` are not _reference-related_ so if you'd "gotten this far", `r` would be bound to the result of converting `p` to `const int*` - a different object. `r = &x;` wouldn't affect `p` (only the converted copy) so `*p = 2;` would still be dereferencing the uninitialized `p`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another instance of the rule that you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const refence.

E.g.

```
X f();

X& r = f(); // illegal
X const& cr = f(); // OK
```

You can convert a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `const int` but the result of that conversion is a new pointer with a different type. You cannot bind an rvalue (such as the result of this conversion) to a non-const reference, only to a const reference, e.g.

```
const int* const& pb = pa; // pb is not bound directly to pa but to
                           // the result of converting pa to const int*
```